# Using Angular 2 components throughout a non-Angular app

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a fork of a preexisting, mature, non-Angular web app. I also have some existing Angular 2 components from a separate app that I wish to reuse. I would like to sprinkle the existing Angular components into the non-Angular app in various places. I would like to know if this is possible and advisable. Note that this is similar but not identical to [Sprinkling Angular 2 components inside a non-angular page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35418243/sprinkling-angular-2-components-inside-a-non-angular-page)
. I have a more specific scenario that I describe below.

Currently, I have figured out how to add single instances of these Angular components by bootstrapping a module that wraps my desired component. E.g. if I want to insert AppComponent into my existing non-Angular app:

In *app.module.ts:*

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

In *app.component.ts:*

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app'
  template: '<span>{{value}}</span>'
  ...
})
export class AppComponent { 
   public value: string;
   ...
 }
```

Whenever I want an AppComponent, I simply append a `my-app` element and bootstrap the module as follows:

```
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

This works perfectly fine and gives the exact results I want *for a single instance of AppComponent*. However, my use cases require that I have *two simultaneous instances of AppComponent* in separate places of the DOM. If I attempt to bootstrap AppModule a second time, the core Angular code attaches the second AppModule to the `my-app` element that appears first in the DOM, effectively erasing my first instance of AppModule. Is there a way to tell Angular which `my-app` element to append to? Or is there any way around this?

**HTML Example**:

Let's say I append a `<my-app>` to `<body>`. Then my HTML looks like:

```
<body>
  <my-app>
  </my-app>
</body>
```

Next, if I call `platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);` and set `value = '111'` anywhere in the AppComponent, my HTML looks like:

```
<body>
  <my-app>
    <span>111</span>
  </my-app>
</body>
```

Then I add another `my-app` selector to the HTML, so it looks like:

```
<body>
  <my-app>
    <span>111</span>
  </my-app>
  <my-app>
  </my-app>
</body>
```

Then, if I call `platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);` and set `value = '222'` in the newly created AppComponenet anywhere in the AppComponent logic my HTML looks like:

```
<body>
  <my-app>
    <span>222</span>
  </my-app>
  <my-app>
  </my-app>
</body>
```

when I would like the desired result to be:

```
<body>
  <my-app>
    <span>111</span>
  </my-app>
  <my-app>
    <span>222</span>
  </my-app>
</body>
```

**In summary:** Is it possible and advisable to use Angular components throughout a non-Angular app? Is it possible to have 2 visible instances of the same Angular Module simultaneously?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you add some html that illustrates your problem? Shortly it's possible

Comment: @yurzui I just updated the OP with an HTML example. Let me know if it's still unclear.

Comment: can you give some examples of how you manage to add angular components to non angular applications? please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following your scenario i would write the following code:

```
let bootstrapComponentFn: (node: HTMLElement) => void;

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule).then((moduleRef: 

  NgModuleRef<AppModule) => {
    const appRef = moduleRef.injector.get(ApplicationRef);
    const zone: NgZone = moduleRef.injector.get(NgZone);
    const rootComponentFactory = (moduleRef as any).bootstrapFactories[0];  

    bootstrapComponentFn = (node) => {
      zone.run(() => {
        const compRef = rootComponentFactory.create(Injector.NULL, [], node);
       appRef.attachView(compRef.hostView);
      })
    }; 
  });
}
```

Some time later

```
setTimeout(function() {
  let node = document.createElement('my-app');
  document.body.appendChild(node);

  bootstrapComponentFn(node);
}, 2000);
```

See also **[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/aChQJh55GRutiP7EJ60E?p=preview)**